# JSON data arrage/ reorder by monthwise

Tags: javascript, json

I need to convert json in better format like "expected" JSON object. Currently i have odd disordered months(in terms of months) objects and in DOM i can't filter it out accordingly. I need to reorder completely...like 2015-01,2015-02, 2015-03....

```
Var myJson = [{"month":"2015-03", "name":"sg"},
              {"month":"2015-03", "name":"pi"},
              {"month":"2015-06", "name":"sg"},
              {"month":"2015-06", "name":"pi"},
              {"month":"2015-01", "name":"sg"},
              {"month":"2015-01", "name":"pi"},
              {"month":"2015-02", "name":"sg"},
              {"month":"2015-02", "name":"pi"}
             ];
var expected = [{"month":"2015-01", "name":"sg"},
              {"month":"2015-01", "name":"pi"},
              {"month":"2015-02", "name":"sg"},
              {"month":"2015-02", "name":"pi"},
              {"month":"2015-03", "name":"sg"},
              {"month":"2015-03", "name":"pi"},
              {"month":"2015-06", "name":"sg"},
              {"month":"2015-06", "name":"pi"}
             ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since myJson is an array you can use the Array.sort function like so:

```
myJson.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.month > b.month;
});
```

This will return the array in the order that you would like.

But note this is doing a string sort and not a numerical one. For a better result I would suggest you String.split the month values on the "-" and then parseInt the month and year values seperately. From there you can do a numeric sort on year and month however you like.